# Open NSViewController As Sheet on MainMenu.xib

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, cocoa

I've opened new Cocoa Project using Xib instead of Storyboard. I would like to open a sheet view controller when button "Livelli" is clicked. Button "Livelli" is in the MainMenu.xib.

I connected button "Livelli" to perform action and wrote the following code:

```
@IBAction func LivelliBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
    window.contentViewController?.presentViewControllerAsSheet(LevelScrollController())
    Swift.print("abc")
}
```

LevelScrollController is a NSViewController that will show a custom NSView and button to close itself.

The console shows "abc", so we need understand that "LivelliBtn" is executed when the Button is clicked but no sheets are opened!

Moreover if I edit the function "LivelliBtn" as following:

```
@IBAction func LivelliBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
    window.contentViewController = LevelScrollController()
    window.contentViewController?.presentViewControllerAsSheet(LevelScrollController())
    Swift.print("abc")
}
```

The presentViewControllerAsSheet method works right. The problem is that I replaced the background view controller and when I close the sheet I don't return to previous view...

How can I show sheet on mainmenu windows?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I result that problem creating a second "MainViewController" that replaces MainMenu.

In AppDelegate I added this lines

```
 func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    window.contentViewController = MainViewController()

}
```

where MainViewController is a ViewController that class the sheet on itself